# Evaluating $\int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{\mathrm{e}^{-i k a \cos\phi \sin\theta}}{1+\cos\phi \sin\theta}\,\mathrm d\phi$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, complex-integration, residue-calculus

How to simplify the following equation:

$$\int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{\mathrm{e}^{-i k a \cos\phi  \sin\theta}}{1+\cos\phi \sin\theta}\,\mathrm d\phi$$

where $k$, $a$ and $\theta$ can be regarded as the constants, and $0<\theta<\frac{\pi}{2}$. Call $\sin\theta=b$ for brevity.

Attempt:

As Von Neumann pointed out, which is really helpful, using the residues theorem,
$$\frac{2}{ib}\int_{|z|=1} \frac{\exp\left(-ikab\left(\frac{z^2+1}{2z}\right)\right)}{z^2 + \frac{2}{b}z + 1}\ \text{d}z$$
Where does the pole locate?
$$z_{1,\ 2} = -\frac{1}{b}\pm \sqrt{\frac{1}{b^2}-1}$$

noted that:  $\frac{1}{b}=\frac{1}{\sin(\theta)}>1$, then only one pole within the circle is considered,where 
$$z_{1} = -\frac{1}{b}+ \sqrt{\frac{1}{b^2}-1}$$

Using the residues theorem, I got the result 
$$\frac{2\pi}{\cos\theta}\exp(ika)$$ 
Then I programmed the original integral and the derived result, there are discrepancies.  My question is that should we consider the numerator when using residues theorem? That is
 $$\exp\left(-ikab\left(\frac{z^2+1}{2z}\right)\right)$$ because using the pole $z_{1}$ we can derive that 
$$\cos\phi =\frac{z^2+1}{2z}=\frac{\left(-\frac{1}{b}+\sqrt{\frac{1}{b^2}-1}\right)^2+1}{2\left(-\frac{1}{b}+\sqrt{\frac{1}{b^2}-1}\right)} = -\frac{1}{b}=-\frac{1}{\sin\theta}$$

As it is shown that $$\cos\phi=-\frac{1}{\sin\theta}$$ which conflicts with each other. Could someone help? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: How to integral it further? And I would like to get a more concise formula

Comment: I have checked several books, like "Tables of Integrals, Series and Products (7ed, Elsevier, 2007 )" by I.S. Gradshteyn, and “Nouvelles tables d'intégrales définies” by Haan, D. Bierens de (David Bierens), I could not find the solution for this kind of integral. I don't know how to simplify it further, I would appreciate it if someone can help

Answer (score 1):

Methinks we can appreciate it carefully with residues theorem.

First of all we step into the complex plane with the usual rules for sine and cosines, that is:

$$\mathcal{J} = \phi \to e^{i\psi} = z ~~~~~~~ \cos\phi \to \ \frac{1}{2}\left(z + \frac{1}{z}\right) ~~~~~~~ \text{d}\phi = \frac{\text{d}z}{iz}$$

We will also call $\sin\theta = b$ for brevity.

The integral becomes (arrange it a bit)

$$\frac{1}{2i}\int_{|z|=1} \frac{\exp\left(-ikab\left(\frac{z^2+1}{2z}\right)\right)}{1 + \frac{b}{2}\frac{z^2+1}{z}}\ \frac{\text{d}z}{z}$$

That is,

$$\frac{1}{ib}\int_{|z|=1} \frac{\exp\left(-ikab\left(\frac{z^2+1}{2z}\right)\right)}{z^2 + \frac{2}{b}z + 1}\ \text{d}z$$

Poles occurs at $$z_{1,\ 2} = -\frac{1}{b}\pm \sqrt{\frac{1}{b^2}-1}$$

Now by residues theorem:

$$\mathcal{J} = 2\pi i \frac{1}{ib} \sum_{z_k} \lim_{z\to z_k} (z-z_k)f(z)|_{z = z_k}$$

Where

$$f(z) = \frac{\exp\left(-ikab\left(\frac{z^2+1}{2z}\right)\right)}{(z-z_1)(z - z_2)}$$

Can you proceed?

Doing the calculation you shall obtain:

$$\frac{2\pi}{b}\left(\frac{e^{-2 i a \sqrt{\frac{1}{b^2}-1} b k}}{2 \sqrt{\frac{1}{b^2}-1}} -\frac{e^{2 i a \sqrt{\frac{1}{b^2}-1} b k}}{2 \sqrt{\frac{1}{b^2}-1}}\right) = -\frac{2\pi}{b}\frac{i \sin \left(2 a \sqrt{\frac{1}{b^2}-1} b k\right)}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{b^2}-1}} = -\frac{2\pi}{b}\frac{i b \sin \left(2 a \sqrt{1-b^2} k\right)}{\sqrt{1-b^2}}$$

Eventually:

$$-2\pi i\frac{ \sin \left(2 a \sqrt{1-b^2} k\right)}{\sqrt{1-b^2}}$$

Where $b = \sin\theta$.

I will check this again later, for the sake of correctness.

Comment: Thank you very much, I really appreciate that. Could you please have a check on the arranged integral, should it be 2 times? And I programmed the derived concise equation and found there are discrepancies from the original integral, especially when \theta is small. Example, if \theta=0 then the original integral equals to 2*pi. Is it caused by not all the poles can be reached in the integral? In addition, \theta is from 0 to pi/2, I'm not familiar with residues theorem, and looking forward to your help again –

Comment: Hi, Neumann, could you please have a check again when you are avaliable? I calculated the integral to be 2*PI*exp(ika)/cos(\theta), I'm not sure if it is correct...

Comment: @xinggz Sure! I will check it again as soon as possible. I am also thinking about giving a different approach (not with residues). I have to think a little bit about!

Comment: @Neumann  Looking forward, thank you very much, cause this problem puzzles me a long time